How to combine @tanstack/react-router Link component with React MUI Link component?
I'm using the Tanstack Router Link component to navigate ( typesafe ) through my app. But for the UI I want to rely on the React MUI Link component.
This is my current approach using both combined ( playground for reproduction )
    <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}>
      <MuiLink underline="hover" color="inherit">
        Tanstack Link rendered as MUI Link
      </MuiLink>
    </Link>

This feels a little bit wrong to me because I'm using the MUI Link without the href prop. And this looks invalid, the console errors

In HTML, <a> cannot be a descendant of <a>.
This will cause a hydration error.

How do I render a MUI Link but use a Router Link under the hood?

Tanstack router has a createLink to produce components enriched with router properties. Official example:
This solution is for a react 18.0 or lower:
// ... Example from tanstack.com
import * as React from 'react'
import { createLink, LinkComponent } from '@tanstack/react-router'
import { Button, ButtonProps } from '@mui/material'

interface MUILinkProps extends Omit<ButtonProps, 'href'> {
  // Add any additional props you want to pass to the button
}

const MUILinkComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, MUILinkProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return <Button component={'a'} ref={ref} {...props} />
  },
)

const CreatedLinkComponent = createLink(MUILinkComponent)

export const CustomLink: LinkComponent<typeof MUILinkComponent> = (props) => {
  return <CreatedLinkComponent preload={'intent'} {...props} />
}

However, when I'm trying to use this as a slot for other MUI component, i.e.
<ListItemButton component={CustomLink} ... >

I'm getting MUI warning:
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

The explanation of this warning is given here https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs, and I use a slightly simplied version without extra wrapper component to avoid warning:
// ... MyLink.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { createLink, LinkComponent } from '@tanstack/react-router';
import { Link as MuiLink, LinkProps as MuiLinkProps } from '@mui/material';

type MUILinkProps = Omit<MuiLinkProps, 'href'>;

const MUILinkComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, MUILinkProps>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return <MuiLink ref={ref} {...props} />;
  }
);

export const MyLink: LinkComponent<typeof MUILinkComponent> =
  createLink(MUILinkComponent);

Now we can use typesafe component with both MUI and Tanstack properties combined:
<MyLink to="/" preload="intent" sx={{ color: "inherit" }}>
   Tanstack Link rendered as MUI Link
</MyLink>

stackblitz playground
